# Excel Ctrl-C slow in system file with many macros

Tags: vba, excel

I work in an entirely excel based system which has a lot of VBA macros involved and the problem is whenever the file with all macros is open then Ctrl-C will cause the computer to think for 2 seconds before allowing me to continue and paste. The loading circle comes up. If I instead press the Copy button on the Home tab of excel, there is no loading and it copies and is immediately ready for paste. It is only when the file with macros is open, and it causes it to happen in not only the file, but in any other workbook that is open.

No macros are called when Ctrl C is pressed. What could be slowing the copy down from simply using the shortcut instead of pressing the button in the menu?

Update: It seems to happen with any keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Can you show your macro?

Comment: There is tens of thousands of lines of VBA I didn't write so I can't tell exactly which macro is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Slowness could be caused by events in the macros that evaluate what just happened in Excel, for example the `Keypress` event or `Application.OnKey`. You may need to deactivate all macros and then activate them one by one to find which ones are responsible for the slowness.

Comment: I think you are on to something.  There are some macros tied to keys and they take about the same amount of time even though they should be instant. There is far too much VBA code to go through in this case to narrow the search. Can you think of any other searchable code/events that trigger from keyboard shortcuts? There are no Keypress events.

Comment: I added Application.OnKey to my answer as another candidate.

Comment: Thanks. I did attempt deleting modules and it appears simply by reducing the number of modules it speeds up.  The more modules I delete, the more it speeds up. I don't know why this would be the case, the copy button still operates quickly. I guess excel could be scanning all the macros for the key events. I am running excel 2010 btw.